# Getting MvxAutoCompleteTextView to work

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am working on an android app with Xamarin and I use MVVMCross for it.
Now I want to use the MvxAutoCompleteTextView but I cannot get it to work.

I made a sample and cannot get it correctly

Here follows my code:
The autocomplete view:

```
<Mvx.MvxAutoCompleteTextView
     android:id="@+id/actSignal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:completionThreshold="1"
     local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/searchitemview"
     local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; PartialText ItemSearchTerm; SelectedObject Item;" />
```

The ItemView I use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    local:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemClass> _items;
    private ItemClass _item;
    private string _searchTerm;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemClass> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set => SetProperty(ref _items, value);
    }

    public ItemClass Item
    {
        get => _item;
        set => SetProperty(ref _item, value);
    }

    public string ItemSearchTerm
    {
        get => _searchTerm;
        set => SetProperty(ref _searchTerm, value);
    }

    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass>
        {
            new ItemClass
            {
                Name = "Test1",
            },
            new ItemClass
            {
                Name = "Test2",
            },
            new ItemClass
            {
                Name = "Test3",
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**When I run it and type something in it I get the following in the output window**

```
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 15.18 Wait starting for T
```

This is the github where I put my sample: [Github](https://github.com/kevingoos/MvxAutoCompleteTest)

Comment: Here is an example about how to use [MvxAutoCompleteTextView](https://github.com/JimWilcox3/MvxAutoCompleteTest).

Comment: I already saw that example looked for a mistake I made but I cannot find any.

Comment: Modify the code in this project, when I don't use `MvxItemTemplate` for `MvxAutoCompleteTextView`  all works fine, is there any problem?

Comment: Yea I got that working. But now the problem is that I want to use a custom template with more info then only the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I made a sample and cannot get it correctly

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `ItemClass` class, complete code like this :

```
public class ItemClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _age;
        }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Age is " + Age + ", Name is " + Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to use a custom template with more info then only the name.

Use a custom template for `MvxAutoCompleteTextView` :

```
 <MvxAutoCompleteTextView
      ...
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/searchitemview"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; PartialText CurrentTextHint; SelectedObject SelectedObject;" />
```

In `searchitemview.axml`, binding properties that you have difine in your `ItemClass` class :

```
<LinearLayout
  ...
  <TextView
      ...
      local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
  <TextView
      ...
      local:MvxBind="Text Age" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Use it in your `FirstViewModel` class :

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private static ObservableCollection<ItemClass> AutoCompleteList;

    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        AutoCompleteList = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass>()
         {
             new ItemClass
             {
                 Name = "Test1",
                 Age = 11
             },
             new ItemClass
             {
                 Name = "Test2",
                 Age = 12
             },
             new ItemClass
             {
                 Name = "Test3",
                 Age = 13
             }
        };
    }

    private ItemClass _SelectedObject;
    public ItemClass SelectedObject
    {
        get { return _SelectedObject; }
        private set
        {
            _SelectedObject = new ItemClass { Name = value.Name ,Age = value.Age};
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedObject");
        }
    }

    private List<ItemClass> _items = new List<ItemClass>();
    public List<ItemClass> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new List<ItemClass>();
            }
            return _items;
        }
        set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }

    private string _currentTextHint;
    public string CurrentTextHint
    {
        get
        { return _currentTextHint; }
        set
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Partial Text Value Sent {0}", value);
            //Setting _currentTextHint to null if an empty string gets passed here
            //is extremely important.
            if (value == "")
            {
                _currentTextHint = null;
                SetSuggestionsEmpty();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _currentTextHint = value;
            }

            if (_currentTextHint.Trim().Length < 2)
            {
                SetSuggestionsEmpty();
                return;
            }

            var list = AutoCompleteList.Where(i => (i.Name.ToString() ?? "").ToUpper().Contains(_currentTextHint.ToUpper()));
            if (list.Count() > 0)
            {
                Items = list.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                SetSuggestionsEmpty();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetSuggestionsEmpty()
    {
        Items = new List<ItemClass>();
    }
}
```

**Effect  :**

[image]

Comment: Just to take into account because I've been struggling with this a while, it's super important that the binded `ItemsSource` gets reassigned completely when you change its items, i.e. `Items = list.ToList();` because otherwise `Items.AddRange(list)` won't work.